# Blur video every 3 seconds continuously

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to do my video overlay every 3 seconds and stretch it till the end of the video.
I used the above command and found that it met the requirement to overlay the video, but its timing is out of control. Here is what I have tried

[0:v]select='if(gt(random(0), 0.02), 1, 20)':n=2 [tmp], boxblur=2:2, [tmp] interleave

Comment: I don't see any overlay in your command. Unclear what you are tying to do. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Trim the cropped portion.

ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:47,crop=450:200:150:1000,boxblur=10[fg];   [0:v][fg]overlay=150:1000:eof_action=pass[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart blurredsection.mp4

Comment: Here it repeats. Why do we use trim?